# Rules for Joining by Past Participle

Tags: sentence-construction, past-participles, participles

The sentences below have different subjects.

1. I saw a child.
2. He was burnt.

But we can join/add them
using a past participle, and write-

3. I saw a burnt child.

I have not been able to find any rule that actually tells me how to combine/join two sentences with two different subjects using a past participle, can anyone provide me a reference, perhaps a link?

Also I am looking for all the rules for joining sentences using only past participles (where past participle can be used, e.g. reduced adjective clause), please help.

Thanks.

Comment: You have not joined those two sentences. You took a past participle (burnt) and used it *as an adjective*.   However, see a burnt child is odd. Burnt chicken would not be so odd. It would refer to the whole chicken. Are you referring to the whole child? Perhaps you should change this to steak or chicken because the child example is, quite frankly, *shocking*. Not shocking would be: I saw a child who was badly burnt.

Comment: @Lambie - even a child who was badly burnt (or burned) is not a pleasant thing to think about, and I wonder at the mentality that produces the image so readily. Although recent news stories may have something to do with it.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Sure. That's what I was trying to say without banging anyone on the head, as it were.

Comment: @Lambie if it is not joining can you plz suggest the term for combining two sentences into one, so I can edit, also I found burnt child example, it is not intentionally constructed, so plz overlook. Note that the main question is how to use past participle to combine multiple simple sentences, so plz comment on that, thanks.

Comment: If you have a relative clause, and rewrite the sentence to simplify that relative clause to a participial phrase, that's called **reducing** the relative clause.  It looks like what you're asking about is the same idea, but with two separate sentences instead of one complex (i.e. clause-containing) sentence.  So, I would still call "the term for combining two sentences into one" **reduction**.  If you're not familiar with relative clause reduction, here is an example: "I saw a fish *that was swimming*" becomes "I saw a fish *swimming*."

Comment: With sentences: "We have a shed. It was built last year." --> "We have a shed *built last year*." The subject ("it") and a form of the verb 'to be' ("was") were both deleted from the second sentence, leaving only the phrase "built last year" which now modifies "shed."  The deletion of the subject (usually of a relative clause, so a word like "who," "which" or "that") plus a form of the linking verb (is, was, etc.) is called **whiz-deletion** -- there is a nice definition of this here: https://english.stackexchange.com/tags/whiz-deletion/info

Comment: You need to give us an example of what you are looking for. A past participle cannot join two sentences.

Comment: "*I saw a car.*" "*It was red.*" These two sentences can be expressed as one: "*I saw a red car.*" There's no difference between "burnt" and "red" in this context. They're both simply adjectives.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I modified the example:

> I saw a chicken.  It was burnt.

The 2 sentences can be combined:

> I saw a chicken **which was burnt**.

We can [reduce the above relative clause](https://www.grammarwiz.com/reduced-relative-clauses.html):

> ... we can in cases reduce relative clauses with just a past particle.  We can do this if the sentence has the verb 'to be' or 'to have' and only a past participle. In this case we can move the past participle to before the modified noun:

> The glass, **which is stained**, needs cleaning

> The **stained** glass needs cleaning

Our relative clause could similarly be reduced to

> I saw a **burnt** chicken.

where the [past participle *burnt* is used as an adjective](https://www.merriam-webster.com/grammar/is-burnt-acceptable-as-the-past-tense-of-burn#:%7E:text=Both%20burned%20and%20burnt%20are,more%20common%20in%20American%20English.).

More examples on the use of the **past participle burnt** as an **adjective**, as in *burnt toast* and *burnt sugar*, are in the same link.